# is it possible to add uiview with big frame into uiview with small frame

Tags: ios, uiview

In my app, I need to add subview in another view but my issue is that height and width of parentView is 50*50 and height of subview is 150*150 so how can I add this? because when I add this view, rest portion of subview is getting cropped.

Comment: Can you please share your code, for better understanding. You can use a scroll view to achieve this functionality

Comment: You can `setClipsToBound:` to `FALSE`. You can also make the parentView bigger (if needed). Depends on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: i dont want to make parentview bigger i just want to make subview smaller but after adding content i want to make its size smaller.@Larme

Comment: like first i will put some date in view A(100*100) then i want to made size of that view (50*50) without cropping and i want to add that view in view B (50*50)

Answer (score 0):

The edges are bounded in the smaller UIView. Because the UIView is smaller it is going to crop out the larger subview. if you still want the super view to be 50x50 and don't want the larger subview cropped out then turn off `setClipsToBound` property of the UIView:

Swift: `view.setClipsToBound = false`
Objective-C: `[view setClipsToBound:NO];`

Another solution is just to make the subview smaller or make the superview containing the large subview larger.

Comment: However, this means you won't receive any touch events in the parts of the larger view that are outside of the smaller parent view.

Comment: contentView.addSubview(DrawingViewCollection[i - 1]) this is my code contentview size is (50*50) while drawingview size is (100*100)